# $evalAsync not working with AWS dynamodb call

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have an issue where an array ($scope.wallet) is not being updated with data from my dynamodb query. here is the query:

```
function queryForCoupon(couponID){
    var couponParams = {
        "TableName":"coupons",
        "KeyConditions":{
            "couponID" :{
                "AttributeValueList":[
                    {
                        "S": couponID
                    }
                ],
                "ComparisonOperator":"EQ"
            }
        },
        "Select": "ALL_ATTRIBUTES"
    }
    db.query(couponParams,
        function(err, data) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {

                $scope.$evalAsync(function () { $scope.wallet.push(data.Items[0]); });
            }

        });
}
```

When I console.log(data.Items[0]) the correct data is there, but later on when I console.log() on the wallets contents nothing is there. I've tried $scope.apply and $scope.timeout as well with no luck.

Any thoughts?